# Creating Executable Zip Archives With Packages in the Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.7, python-module

I feel this question needs a better title and I will amend it if someone suggests something better. The problem is I'm not sure of the terminology of the feature that I'm using here.

The best way to describe my problem is to show what I've done. The project is here: https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor

This project is setup so it can be executed as a module. For example, from the project root someone could do this:

```
python3 -m quendor
```

I also have a build script to generate an in-memory zip (if I'm using that terminology correctly):

https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor/blob/master/build.py

That works in that if you run `build.py` it will generate a `quendor.py` file that executes the entire project. That worked fine **up until I included other directories (like my `utilities` and `zinterface`).**

With the project as it is in the repo right now, if you run the build (`.\build.py`) and then run the generated file:

```
./quendor.py
```

You get the following error:

```
File "./quendor.py/quendor/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quendor.zinterface'
```

So a key point: **if all of my files are in the same directory (i.e., in `quendor`) this build script works fine in terms of producing an executable script file.**

But once I include the subdirectories and files in those directories, things go south on me with the above error.

I'm sure all the files are being gathered. I handle that starting on line 18 (https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor/blob/master/build.py#L18). And if you were to add to line 24 this statement:

```
print(f"* {file_path}")
```

You would see it outputs the following:

```
* quendor/__init__.py
* quendor/__version__.py
* quendor/zinterface/fileio.py
* quendor/utilities/messages.py
* quendor/__main__.py
```

So I'm suspecting it might have to do with the code where I write the string at line 28 (https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor/blob/master/build.py#L28). I feel I have to do more to let the executable zipped script file know about the modules.

But I'm not sure if (1) I'm accurate and (2) even if I'm accurate, if that's possible. I'm finding I'm in a bit over my head here.

Any thoughts would be appreciated and I'm happy to update with any necessarily clarifications or terminology.

Comment: in `File "./quendor.py/quendor/__main__.py"` it should have been `from . import zinterface`. Maybe a non-python 3 compliant package? not sure

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure either. I tried relative imports like this originally: `from .zinterface import fileio as zio` but it leads to the same error. I know that's not the exact same as yours. I tried yours exactly but then it's not clear how to call the function from that file as I do (https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor/blob/master/quendor/__main__.py#L53). Python's module system has always been problematic for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Don’t generate a file with the same name as your package/module name.

Comment: Hmm. So in my line 39 of `build.py` I changed this line (`python_file = package_directory + ".py"`) to this (`python_file = "quendor_script" + ".py"`). If I'm understanding correctly, that's what you're referring to. In that case, I do generate a `quendor_script.py` file (rather than `quendor.py`) thus the script no longer has the same name as the module. Executing that, however, leads to the same error. (Interesting thought, however. I didn't even think about the similar naming.)

Comment: What if you add `__init__.py` into `zinterface` directory?

Comment: Interesting thought. I tried that. I added a blank `__init__.py` file into `zinterface`. I get the same error. I also tried adding the following line the `__init__.py` file: `from quendor.zinterface import *` I was thinking maybe if the init file actually did the importing. I confirmed that it still works to run as a module. But when generating the script via `build.py` and then executing it, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Sorry, the new version of this question (turned into an answer) needs to be rolled back. This version destroys the context that other people have answered, and in any case, no-one who reads this answer will understand what the original problem was.

Comment: The version history of this question (including the overwrite) [is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56203190/revisions). You can copy anything from there into your answer if you wish.

Comment: Well, actually no one did answer -- except to tell me the answer is that it's not possible. I found the answer on my own using hints from those comments. I kept the problem intact so the context is entirely present, which is I why I show the previous link (that was the problem) and I clearly describe what the problem was. I can't see any way that this is unclear at all but I'm willing to stand corrected.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you were the first to get the answer - you can add your material in your answer, so that all answers are on an equal footing. Edits are still welcome on the question, from you or anyone else, but the nature of the question (as it stood before you found the answer) must be preserved. If it were to be rewritten in the past tense then it would no longer be a question that asks how to solve a problem, which is critical to the required format here.

Comment: Got it. Kind of silly because the nature of the question was preserved. In fact, it was clarified a bit. The problem is now it's actually a bit inconsistent since the links are now not correct. But whatever works.

Comment: (Some people post a Q&A having solved an interesting problem just out of helpfulness, and it is great that they do. However they often struggle for the same reason that is emerging here - they are required to post the question that they would have had prior to discovering the answer, as if they temporarily do not know the answer. That allows other people to answer too - after all, a better answer may still come along).

Comment: Fair point. I just know had I come across my revised question, it would have made a lot more sense, particularly when I read the other responses. Now it seems disconnected a bit. But I do get your point and understand where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it turns out I found a way to do this! It required using `os.walk` rather than `os.listdir`. This required taking a few ideas that people here discussed. Here is the script that does the trick:

https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor/blob/master/build.py

You can compare that with my [previous commit](https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor/commit/fbd6d810d371441fab76c69a6417c2d6f9aaec98#diff-2955d5257f635de1df53f55a171ca5c7) that was trying to handle this a different way.

Eldritch was right that I couldn't just flatten the directory nor could I just add imports to the string I was writing to the final zip file. Jean-François was correct that I had to focus on the `__main__.py` that was being generated. My contribution was figuring out `os.walk()` and then [parameterizing the written string](https://github.com/jeffnyman/quendor/blob/master/build.py#L27) to handle the different directories.

Finally, this solution does require, as per HTF's suggestion, that I put an empty `__init__.py` file in each package.

With my solution in place, you can run `build.py` which then generates the `quendor.py` script. That script then executes correctly, in terms of recognizing the imports to various packages.

Comment: Btw there is a [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html) module that will create zip archive with auto generated `__main__` file.

Answer (score 1):

So it won't let me comment unless I have more reputation but I can post an answer. Even though I don't have an answer, but rather a comment. I think the above comment was not meant for your actual `__main__.py` file but rather the one that is getting generated in your `quendor.py` file. You might want to try adding the import statements to your packed string that you write.

For example, see what happens if on line 32 you add this: `import quendor.zinterface.fileio as zio`. (Don't replace the line that's there. Just put my line and then keep your others.) I'm not sure how the zip process works but if it tries to mirror the module process that should work. However, if it doesn't, that won't work. You might also just want to try doing `import quendor.zinterface`. By itself that won't work but it would be interesting to see if it gave you a different error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out and I do get the same errors. However, I tried a relative import and I did get a different error. To be clear, I added a line in my `writestr()` based on what  Jean-François suggested: `from . import zinterface`. When I did that, generated the `quendor.py` file and ran it, I got a new error:  `attempted relative import with no known parent package`. So maybe that's part of the issue here.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, then that's telling you it's not possible. I'm saying that because that means it's not treating what gets zipped up as a package. Although that makes me wonder why the script works at all even when the files are all in one directory. The line you have (31) that says `from quendor import __main__` should actually be setting up the parent package. The trick is the directories. For Python they are modules, but the zip is probably just treating them as directories and so when it comes to the import it can't execute that.

Comment: Actually, the more I look at this the more you shouldn't have to change the writestr() that you put in place. It wouldn't matter anyway. That's just bootstrap stuff to get the execution going. So if there is a fix it would have to be with how you're doing the imports but Python's system of importing modules isn't terribly flexible and it sounds like you've tried the main things. I'll play around more and see if I can figure something out. You got me curious.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Now I'm wondering if I shouldn't somehow flatten the hierarchy of files when I bring them in to the build. But then that would require changing the imports, I'm sure. And I would still need it to work both as a module execution and via the script.

Comment: You can't really do that, though. If you do that it would mean your `quendor/zinterface/fileio.py` will now be just `quendor/fileio.py` and that means your import in `__main__.py` wouldn't resolve even if the import system was working.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with just about every variation of import and file gathering that I can think of with your repo, there's a good news / bad news thing.

- The bad news is that the answer is this: it isn't possible.
- The good news is this: you do have a working implementation if you just keep all files in the `quendor` directory rather than having subdirectories.

The other good news is you stumbled on something, and posed a problem, that Python gurus aren't able to answer. And there's a certain pleasure to be found in that! I guarantee you will not get an answer to this that works (except for the "all files in one directory" solution).

A refinement to the answer is that if you're setting up the program to run as a module anyway, just use a pip configuration. That basically does the same thing that you want but without having to go through the contortions. (Unless there's a reason you were doing the build the way you were rather than using pip.)

Comment: Huh. Thanks but yeah I guess I'm finding I'm agreeing with you here. I was also checking out this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html . Interestingly that doesn't cover subdirectories at all. I try to run `python3 -m zipapp quendor` and while that works, execution leads to "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quendor'" I tried their alternative way (`python -m zipapp -p "interpreter" quendor`) and that gives the same issue.

Comment: As one final thought, you might want to try something like this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html (with examples https://pymotw.com/2/zipimport/). But like most things in Python, it's poorly documented and only works sometimes. Python's import system has always been crap compared to just about any regularly used language out there. Just go with pip and I think your life will be easier.